# Nested TreeMap sorting

Tags: java, hashmap

consider the following code:

```
static TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, Integer>> myMap = new TreeMap<>(new 
    Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return o2.compareTo(o1);
    }
});
```

The outer TreeMap has string as key and sort by reverse lexicographically (already done) and I want to sort the inner TreeMap by reverse lexicographically, how should I write the Comparator?

Comment: You shouldn't change the comparator at all.  You need to use the same comparator, a second time, when you construct the inner maps.

Comment: Use the same comparator on the inner tree map?  It's not clear what you don't understand.

Comment: yes, I want to use a customize comparator in the inner TreeMap.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `.reversed()` method that does what you want.

```
 // for keys
 myMap.comparator().reversed(); 

 // for values
 myMap.forEach((s, stringStringTreeMap) -> stringStringTreeMap.comparator().reversed());
```